# Itext7 xfa form

Tags: .net, pdf, itext7, xfa

I have a pdf which I am trying to automatically fill with .NET and itext7. I am using the solution mentioned here(https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-fill-xfa-form-using-itext-without-breaking-usage-rights) to fill the form. This solution is working on one pdf but is breaking the usage rights on other pdf. Any idea why is this error occuring?

Comment: If you shared the non-working PDF, people here could analyze the issue. In general: Non-Adobe XFA support always is error-prone as the publicly available XFA specification is incomplete. This also is why both XFA-in PDF and usage rights signatures have been obsoleted in ISO 32000-2, the current PDF standard.

Comment: Here is the error pdf file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kXmUu1EmAf7MzoW3WJ14ZmxFp-Hr44tI/view?usp=sharing